# Don't understand how to remove custom olcAttributeTypes and olcObjectClasses. Openldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

I created custom olcAttributeTypes and olcObjectClasses via ldapmodify ldif

```
changetype: modify
add: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.7.11.3.1
       NAME 'freshid3'
       EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
       SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
       SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.7.11.3.2
       NAME 'rocketid3'
       EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
       SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
       SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024} )
-
add: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.7.11.3.3
   NAME 'astrofInfo1'
   DESC 'astrofInfo1'
   SUP top
   AUXILIARY
   MAY  (freshid $ rocketid))
```

Those classes are working but i want to remove all and start from stratch. If i look in slad.d dir i see `/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema.ldif` with content

```
# CRC32 c427b1a1
dn: cn=schema
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: schema
structuralObjectClass: olcSchemaConfig
entryUUID: 445fd29a-ebfd-1037-85e2-25e1d38603b9
creatorsName: cn=admin,cn=config
createTimestamp: 20180514200100Z
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 1.7.11.1.1      NAME 'freshid'      EQUALITY caseIgn
 oreMatch      SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch      SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466
 .115.121.1.15 )
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 1.7.11.1.2      NAME 'rocketid'      EQUALITY caseIg
 noreMatch      SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch      SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.146
 6.115.121.1.15{1024} )
olcAttributeTypes: {2}( 1.7.11.3.1      NAME 'freshid3'      EQUALITY caseIg
 noreMatch      SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch      SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.146
 6.115.121.1.15 )
olcAttributeTypes: {3}( 1.7.11.3.2      NAME 'rocketid3'      EQUALITY caseI
 gnoreMatch      SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch      SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.14
 66.115.121.1.15{1024} )
olcObjectClasses: {0}( 1.7.11.1.3  NAME 'astrofData'  DESC 'astrofData'  SUP
  inetOrgPerson  STRUCTURAL  MAY  (freshid $ rocketid))
olcObjectClasses: {1}( 1.7.11.3.3  NAME 'astrofInfo1'  DESC 'astrofInfo1'  S
 UP top  AUXILIARY  MAY  (freshid $ rocketid))
entryCSN: 20220223203521.059097Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20220223203521Z
```

What i tried to remove

1. Create and execute ldif with  content like first one but change `add` to `delete`

```
changetype: modify
delete: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.7.11.3.1
       NAME 'freshid3'
       EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
       SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
       SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.7.11.3.2
       NAME 'rocketid3'
       EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
       SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
       SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{1024} )
-
delete: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.7.11.3.3
   NAME 'astrofInfo1'
   DESC 'astrofInfo1'
   SUP top
   AUXILIARY
   MAY  (freshid $ rocketid))
```

And got error like this

```
ldap_modify: Operations error (1)
```

2. Tried ldif like this

```
changetype: modify
delete: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: (1.7.11.3.1)
olcAttributeTypes: (1.7.11.3.2)
-
delete: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: (1.7.11.3.3)
```

And got this message.

```
ldap_modify: No such attribute (16)
    additional info: modify/delete: olcAttributeTypes: no such value
```

I don't unerstand why i can create but it can't delete :(

Will be supper appriciate for any help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the `olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 1.7.11.1.1 ...` attribute then you have to consider the following LDIF content (in your case the `dn` part may be optional):

```
dn: ...
changetype: modify
delete: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: {0}
```

Note the `olcAttributeTypes: {0}` part.

At LDAP logs level you should see some complaints about some missing parts but I guess you can ignore them as they look informal ones.